# Blazor and Azure function global achitecture

Tags: azure-functions, blazor

I'm working on a blazor server and Web API.

For now I use the blazor website to interact with my data throught the API and most of thoses interactions a short (CRUD).
The API use a Token/Refresh token authentication.

I would like to add functions that use files (10 to 200mb) and use a larger amount of data from the API to combine them. And for this I was thinking about Azure Functions with schema like this :

Blazor -> Azure Blob Storage -> Azure Function -> Azure Blob Storage -> Blazor

I've never used Azure functions and I don't know if it's the right things to do ? Or should I go with another solution/schema ?

Comment: Are you hosting your Blazor server App on Azure?

Comment: @DanielW. yes, the Blazor server and the web Api are on Azure

Comment: In this case why not directly connect to the Azure Blob Storage? For Blazor webassembly I would use functions, but for Blazor Server not.

Comment: so you would use the blazor server to process the file after it has been uploaded to the blob storage ?

Comment: Ok 200 Mb, In that cased Azure Fuctions seams the better way, sorry I did not get hat part. But be aware there is a max runtime on Azure Functions.

Comment: Ok, thank you ! I'll keep looking how to work with thoses files and the functions.